# Why salome-elmer simulation could return LUA error when doing linear elasticity simulation?

Tags: lua

I am using Salome-Elmer and have an LUA error. I found out it may be the reading problem.

```
MAIN: Reading Model: C:\Users\...\case.sif
Caught LUA error:...0-Release/share/elmersolver/lua-scripts/defaults.lua:58: r
LoadInputFile: Scanning input file: C:\Users
```

when I open the Lua file, line 57-58 writes:

```
function readsif(fname)
  local f = assert(io.open(fname), 'r')
```

Anyone knows why? Thanks?

Comment: Typo: `assert(io.open(fname), 'r')` should be `assert(io.open(fname, 'r'))`

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica You are right about that. I updated the code. But it still has error.

Comment: I'm guessing it's not the same error. Please post the new error. Also, your example needs to be reproducible.

Comment: Caught LUA error:...0-Release/share/elmersolver/lua-scripts/defaults.lua:58: C:Users   l393DownloadsElmerLocalCurvedFiberstrig

Comment: In the LUA file it is defined as: local fname = underscored .. "_" .. counter. Do you think it has any problem?